# Upload AAR ( with transitive dependencies ) to SonaType from a private Github repository using Gradle

Tags: maven, github, gradle, aar

Here in my company we're building a Player SDK for android using GMF and Exoplayer as transitive dependencies and we would like to see which one is the best strategy to upload it to a maven repository ( we have a SonaType account ) that allow our clients to download it with a simple compile command.

We've been searching online but we couldn't reach a "perfect" or "ideal" solution. We came across this "gradle-mvn-push" plugin but looks like it's deprecated. Did anyone come across this problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks =)

Comment: Are you asking what is the best way to publish to a maven repo from gradle?

Comment: I'm almost there but there was a problem with the transitive dependencies. It can't seems to work at all hence they are not included even using transitive = true.

    compile(project(':second-level-lib')) {
        transitive=true
    }

Comment: If you're publishing to a maven repo, use the [new `maven-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html). aar's are not accompanied by a pom file by default, you'll have to construct your own. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34914603/745574

Comment: <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>player-sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>asdf</artifactId>
<version>unspecified</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
<artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
<version>23.1.1</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately when including a module as a dependency the resulting pom.xml goes like this.
We are trying to achieve something like the brightcove's skd example ( http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/guides/studio-android-sdk-quick-start.html )