# Android- How to consume aar file in maven build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

I am using `gradle` build for Developer environment and in production environment.
I am using maven build. In my project I am using **Google play services 7.8.0**,
I started using play services `aar` file, but maven build needs a jar file.
so how can i get the jar file or is there a way that i can consume `aar` file maven build?

Comment: You can't use a jar since the google play services has also resources

Comment: Check this SO question [34872382](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872382/manually-adding-aar-with-dependency-pom-iml-file) and [16682847](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about Android maven plugin and:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
   </dependency>
```

I'm not sure if I got you right, but you should use one project management tool for all you environments. That way you avoid problems with differences in dev/release builds! Use gradle everywhere ;)