# gradle api not working for multi project setup in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I have a multi-project setup. Consider two separate apps AppA and AppB. AppA has two library modules modA and modB. modA has a dependency on modB via gradle API.

consider modA `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    api project(":mobB")
}
```

modA has a file `ModASample.kt` which looks like

```
class ModASample{
    fun modASample(){
        println("modASample")
    }
}
```

modB has a file `ModBSample.kt` which looks like

```
class ModBSample{
    fun modBSample(){
        println("modBSample")
    }
}
```

AppA `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":modA")
}
```

from a class in appA `AppASample.kt`

```
class AppASample{

    fun access(){
        val modA = ModASample() //accessible
        val modB = ModBSample() //accessible
    }

}
```

both `ModASample` and `ModBSamle` are accessible which is expected as well because modB is used in modA via `api` access.

The issue arises when I try to extract an `aar` of `modA` and try to use this aar in `AppB`.

AppB has `build.gradle` file which looks like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":modA")
}
```

Now this time an `aar` of modA is prepared and is added as a separate module.

From a class `AppBSample.kt`

```
class AppASample{

    fun access(){
        val modA = ModASample() //accessible
        val modB = ModBSample() // NOT ACCESSIBLE
    }

}
```

Can anyone please provide some insight why is this happening. I was expecting modB will be accessible but that is not the case if direct aar is used.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you placing this aar in modB?

Comment: The context of your follow up question is not very clear. Can you please add to it.

Comment: I looked at some of the comments below, and it seems you want to include modB as a dependency of modA, kind of like how retrofit brings in okhttp, is that a fair statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34914603/2577750)

What I could understand was, while packaging the aar file, the supplied dependency declaring modifiers (api/implementation) does not actually include the dependency files along with the package. Though the modifiers(api/implementation) still stands up for their intended usage, they seemingly are not responsible for actually moving the dependencies into the package.

So for bringing the dependencies along, we need to explicitly package them together. In my case I used [maven publish plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin) to get the dependencies packaged along with the aar.

Answer (score 1):

The AAR doesn't contain transitive dependencies, it doesn't have any pom file with the list of their dependencies.
Check this build.gradle.kts from a library I developed: https://github.com/GiuseppeGiacoppo/RemoteConfig/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

What you can do is define a task that creates a jar file with all the sources.

Since it's a kotlin library and not Android, you should change it with this:

```
val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs)
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the code was just to portray the situation. The library is for Android, has other code than this. But I'll give your suggestion a try. If the AAR doesn't contain transitive dependencies, the scope of implementation and api gradle profiles is limited to just multi module setup? That is quite strange.

Comment: Api and implementation work only at compile time and they're a gradle feature for your gradle project. They guide you to organize in a better way your code along multiple modules. Once you build, your artifact (aar, jar, etc.) won't have info about modules and their dependency mode (api or implementation)