# Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal - Maven publish plugin project gradle

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I have an Android project with multiple modules and I want to publish them to self-hosted maven repo. I earlier had the publishing code present in individual modules and things worked just fine. I am now trying to move the publishing code into the project `build.gradle` so that I can reuse the code. The code inside my individual modules was:

```
afterEvaluate {
        // To avoid publishing the applications inside the project...
        if (!plugins.hasPlugin("android")) {
            publishing {
                publications {
                    mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
                        artifactId "$project.name"
                        from components.release
                    }
                }
                repositories {
                    .... My repo details and credentials .......
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and things worked just fine. When I moved the code to the project `build.gradle`, like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    afterEvaluate {
        // To avoid publishing of the applications inside the project ..
        if (!plugins.hasPlugin("android")) {
            publishing {
                publications {
                    mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
                        artifactId "$project.name"
                        from components.release
                    }
                }
                repositories {
                    .... My reop details and creddentials  .....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I started getting the following error when running the `publish` task:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':mymodule'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
```

Can someone point out the problem here?

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please any update?

Comment: I posted a solution

Answer (score 11):

I solved my problem using this line:

```
from components.findByName('release')
```

here you should put it:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.findByName('release')

                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Using Gradle 8.0 in Android Studio Flamingo (2022.2.1 Patch 2)

Answer (score 8):

check your project level build.gradle and make sure gradle classpath is

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2" or above.
```

This worked for me.

As mentioned by others, you can also check component names by :

```
task comps {
    afterEvaluate {
        println("Components: " + components*.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an important point, as several dependencies I was working with made the assumption of availability of these options. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I came across this after updating AGP for Jitpack. Both the MavenPublication block and the `components.release` line appear to use your build variant name. So if you have a standard debug and release variant it would look like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.my.group'
                artifactId = 'id'
                version = Config.libraryVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you have a build variant with a name other than release, you need to use that:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            productionRelease(MavenPublication) {
                from components.productionRelease
                groupId = 'com.my.group'
                artifactId = 'id'
                version = Config.libraryVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Gradle file does this go in? Where in the file should it be added?

Comment: it goes in your module level build.gradle file

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, I added another **afterEvaluate**.

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

  afterEvaluate {
    // To avoid publishing of the applications inside the project ..
    if (!plugins.hasPlugin("android")) {
        publishing {
            publications {
                mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
                    afterEvaluate {
                       artifactId "$project.name"
                       from components.release
                    }
                }
            }
            repositories {
                .... My reop details and creddentials  .....
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. It just changes the line at which it complains about the failure down one. to the new line for "from components.release"

Comment: @William can you show me your code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/william-ferguson-au/7b1b7161289e9fd57bd3a88f17dfe5b2

Comment: @William https://gist.github.com/BackPackerDz/918e6d47387c86fe6b00bd2fec7f6220 did you try it like that?

Comment: Yes - same error just the line numbers are shunted down one.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of the answers worked for me. And I wouldn't be myself if I didn't try to reverse-engineer it rather than read the docs :)

Turns out, this `components.release` works fine when we're building a `com.android.library`, but not so well when building with the `com.android.application` plugin. If gradle says it doesn't have a `release` component, then let's see what components DOES it have:

```
task comps {
    afterEvaluate {
        println("Components: " + components*.name)
    }
}
```

doing a `./gradlew :app:comps` prints the following:

```
Components: [debug_aab, debug_apk, release_aab, release_apk]
```

If in the `android.buildTypes {}` closure I defined another type, say, `freebie`, `./gradlew :app:comps` will print the following:

```
Components: [debug_aab, debug_apk, release_aab, release_apk, freebie_aab, freebie_apk]
```

It appears that the gradle plugin takes your build variant's name and creates two variants out of it: `${variant}_apk` and `${variant}_aab`.

Now to solve the initial problem, replace

```
publications {
    mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
        artifactId "$project.name"
        from components.release
    }
}
```

with

```
publications {
    mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
        artifactId "$project.name"
        from components.release_apk
    }
}
```

or use the `_aab` one.
If you're using another variant than `release`, replace the `from components.release_apk` part accordingly.

Gradle: 7.3

AndroidStudio: 2021.2.1 Canary 4 (Chipmunk)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2` or above version 3.6
in both `root/build.gradle` and `root/<library_name>/build.gradle`.
Then make sure both plugins were declared in `root/<library_name>/build.gradle` like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

then you can use components.release

You can read this docs https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin#groovy for more information

Answer (score 2):

When using Gradle Plugin 7.x there was a warning showing up:

> Software Components are be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

When migrating an Android library project to Gradle Plugin 8+ follow these steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366104/2115352

Add:

```
android {
    namespace ...
    compileSdk ...
    ...
    publishing {
        singleVariant('release') {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Do this for all modules which are to be published.

Answer (score -2):

I ran against the same error. Solved it with the code below:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = 'mygroup'
                artifactId = 'common'
                version = '1.0.0'
                artifact(bundleReleaseAar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that you have to specify the exact path to the AAR file.
You can find more details in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936807/971355

Answer (score -2):

Ran into a similar error and resolved by applying the android plugin before `afterEvaluate`, so something looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
        ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I got same error, Solved it with the code below.

The actual change is to wrap the `from components.release` line in an additional afterEvaluate block.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    afterEvaluate {
        // To avoid publishing of the applications inside the project ..
        if (!plugins.hasPlugin("android")) {
            publishing {
                publications {
                    mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
                        artifactId "$project.name"
                        //add afterEvaluate block
                        afterEvaluate {
                            from components.release
                        }
                    }
                }
                repositories {
                    .... My reop details and creddentials  .....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You copy pasted my answer

Comment: @Fayçal Typo and everything 