# Automatic creation of software Components removed in Android Gradle Plugin 8

Tags: android, maven, gradle

We have an Android project which uses Android Gradle Plugin 7.X and relies on multiple build variants to publish both .apks and .aabs initially to our Maven repository and on demand to Play Store. The build variants are combined using the **productFlavor** name and **buildConfig** options, and the result is something like *brand1-release*, or *brand2-debug*.

When we publish the resources to Maven, we rely on the **components.build-name-of-variant** with the following code:

```
afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
                publications {
                        brand1Apk(MavenPublication) {
                        groupId = 'apk.release.' + brand1
                        artifactId = 'brand1'
                        from components.**brand1Release_apk** 
                }
...
        }
}
```

Now, with AGP 7 everything works OK, but I noticed this warning

> WARNING: Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the gradle.properties file or use the new publishing DSL.

After upgrading to AGP 8, the publishing breaks because, as expected, the software component , the **brand1Release_apk** part of components.**brand1Release_apk** , is not created automatically.

And this is where my confusion starts.

I found this thread [Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365373/software-components-will-not-be-created-automatically-for-maven-publishing-from) which points to a nice direction about using **singleVariant('release') {}** and **multipleVariants {}** but reading through the documentation for  [ApplicationPublishing](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationPublishing) and [Configure publication variants](https://developer.android.com/build/publish-library/configure-pub-variants) and [LibraryPublishing](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/LibraryPublishing) I get the feeling that these options are more reserved for publishing libraries.
Also, the thread above mentions the **'com.android.library' plugin** and in my case I have all of the above mentioned under the main module of the app which of course uses the **com.android.application plugin**.

Is there are a brave soul to shed some lights on these Gradle conundrums? How can I use the components associated with the build variants in the MavenPublications task under AGP 8?

Comment: For the time being this is the only relevant information I have found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233102275#comment1 .

Comment: Did you figure out a way to solve this?

Comment: No, I still haven't .