Publish own private Android library to own gitlab
I'm working with this tutorial for making internal library for own purposes. I created module, added publishing .gradle file:
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        myPublish (MavenPublication) {
            groupId "id"
            artifactId "utilsmobile"
            version "1.0.0"
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/utilsmobile-release.aar"


            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.named("releaseCompileClasspath").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects//packages/maven"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "utils_pkg"
                value = "token"
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}

and added to the module build.gradle this line:
apply from: "$rootDir/Utils/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"

but I don't see any new Gradle tasks in the gradle dashboard of the Android Studio and don't understand how to release it to the own repository. Maybe I need to declare it as a separate task or what I did wrong?

That is seemingly lacking one configuration of MavenPublication:
from components.java

For comparison: Publish a Java library to a Maven repository

but where to put it? in gradle file for publish or I need to add separate task?

Into myPublish (MavenPublication) { ... }. The name may vary, but you need to add at least one component. The behavior also has changed a bit over time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366104/549372

I added it into pom.withXml {, but the task for publish did not appear in the list of tasks

Read again, this is definitely not what I've wrote. I'd even doubt that you need any of that pom.withXml block or have to manually define any of the dependencies, which have been defined already. Since the publishing behavior changed, you might be dealing with an outdated example. That's one known to be working example of mine: https://github.com/syslogic/agconnect-publishing-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L91

in general it seems to be workable with the command gradle publish, but I received the error - Could not PUT '...utilsmobile/1.0.0/utilsmobile-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 415 from server: Unsupported Media Type, so the problem is resolvable only via gitlab admin panel, or it could be done via script which I'm trying to fix?

See gitlab-http.conf... there might be a rewrite or similar which leads to the MME type's rejection. Just add *.pom and reload the server; then try again and see what happens. There may also be .htaccess overrides in place, depending on the configuration.
