# Android Studio error: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set

Tags: android, react-native

I keep facing this below error from android studio.

I've done all things from this post.

[Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal - Maven publish plugin project gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253670/could-not-get-unknown-property-release-for-softwarecomponentinternal-maven-p)

But nothing doesn't work.

Can you help me?

```
   Build file '/Users/hayat/Documents/chungchunon-RN-frontend/node_modules/expo-camera/android/build.gradle' line: 48
    
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-camera'.
   > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
    at
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365373/software-components-will-not-be-created-automatically-for-maven-publishing-from

Answer (score 3):

It's helped for me.

**gradle.properties**

it was

```
 android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true
```

changed

```
 #android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true
```